# Replace/Update a existing node value in groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

Below is my sample xml.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <MessageHeader xmlns:ns3="http://csi.cingular.com/CSI/Namespaces/Types/Public/CingularDataModel.xsd" xmlns:ns39="http://csi.cingular.com/CSI/Namespaces/Types/Public/MessageHeader.xsd">
         <ns39:TrackingMessageHeader>
            <ns3:infrastructureVersion>86</ns3:infrastructureVersion>
            <ns3:version>222</ns3:version>
            <ns3:messageId>146100035386400076</ns3:messageId>
            <ns3:originatorId>PEEPS</ns3:originatorId>
            <ns3:timeToLive>120000</ns3:timeToLive>
            <ns3:dateTimeStamp>2016-04-18T20:16:19.387Z</ns3:dateTimeStamp>
         </ns39:TrackingMessageHeader>
         <ns39:SecurityMessageHeader>
            <ns3:userName></ns3:userName>
            <ns3:userPassword></ns3:userPassword>
         </ns39:SecurityMessageHeader>
         <ns39:SequenceMessageHeader>
            <ns3:sequenceNumber>1</ns3:sequenceNumber>
            <ns3:totalInSequence>1</ns3:totalInSequence>
         </ns39:SequenceMessageHeader>
      </MessageHeader>    </SOAP-ENV:Header>    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <InquireEnterpriseOrderListRequest xmlns="http://csi.cingular.com/CSI/Namespaces/InquireEnterpriseOrderListRequest.xsd">
         <SelectionCriteria>
            <organizationId>214256542</organizationId>
         </SelectionCriteria>
      </InquireEnterpriseOrderListRequest>    </SOAP-ENV:Body> </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I want to replace "organizationId" this tag value with the value read from file and trigger it using `testRunner.runTestStepByName("InquireEnterpriseOrderList")` once the value is updated in the node.

Can any help in understanding how to update/replace node with new value and re-trigger the API to capture result for many inputs.

Comment: Venki, have you got chance to try the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you what you need to do:

- Read file extract the required value and store it at test case level custom property. Assuming that you are using groovy script test step to do this. So, add the below additional code:

```groovy
//You assign value from your code, for now using dummy assignment
def requiredvalue = '123453'

//Store that value at test case level custom property, say ORGANIZATION_ID
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('ORGANIZATION_ID', requiredValue.toString())
```

- Now, you do not need to update the request. Instead use, property expansion as below, so that SoapUI automatically takes care of the required value from proerties

  `<organizationId>${#TestCase#ORGANIZATION_ID}</organizationId>`

Comment: Used below snippet, getting this errorcontext.testCase.setPropertyValue('ORGANIZATION_ID', temp.toString())
 log.info context.testCase.setPropertyValue('ORGANIZATION_ID', temp.toString())       also, in the request its getting captured as Tue Aug 29 09:53:50 IST 2017:INFO:${#InquireEnterpriseOrderListTestCase#ORGANIZATION_ID} and when its getting triggered gettoing error as "<ns5:description>Encountered a Post-IVP XML Validation Error: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '' is not a valid value for 'integer'.</ns5:description>

Comment: Please elaborate with details.

Comment: I have used below snippet,     for (int i=0;i<inputcount;i++)
{
 log.info "enter inside the loop---" +i
 log.info "request that is being triggered---" +lines.getAt(i)
 def temp=lines.getAt(i)
 log.info "090909090    ---" +temp
 context.testCase.setPropertyValue('ORGANIZATION_ID', temp.toString())
 log.info context.testCase.setPropertyValue('ORGANIZATION_ID', temp.toString())
 } when i use this snippet, i m not able to see the dynamic value in the request, In the request i could see still as "${#TestCase#ORGANIZATION_ID}" same.The actual value is not getting replaced with dynamicvalue.

Comment: i m able to see the required result, modified code according to my requirement. Thanks alot for help

Comment: @venkikasula, [appreciate if you can accept it as answered](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)